When I bake diffuse color I dont have transparenci in my backed image, my backround is black I dont have alpa checker board
I'm baking diffuse color on to texture, I have checked alpha when I created texture, but when I finish baking I'm getting black where it should be alpha checker board.



You didn’t actually show your result here, but on a guess of what it looks like, did you try turning on transparency in the Film panel of the Render tab of the Properties Editor?

@TheLabCat in left up corner is render result  turned on transparency in the Film panel, same resoult

I also notice that the two different screenshots you posted show two different Blender versions, 3.0.0 and 3.4.1. The latest version is 4.2, please always take the habit to notify when you don't use the latest software version, things can be drastically different sometimes. Is there any reason why you don't use the latest, nor even the same version without the same question?

Previewing images with Alpha
It seems that you set your image editor to show only color channels with no alpha:

Please set it back to Color & Alpha to be able to see those channels correctly:


Your model doesn't seem to have any transparent or see-through areas, and the little bit of your node tree we can see doesn't seem to have any of them either.
Alpha
What is it
The Principled BSDF's Alpha property controls the transparency of the surface, with 1.0 fully opaque and 0.0 fully transparent.
How to use it
If you need variations of transparency: have some texture nodes plugged in the Alpha socket, otherwise manually set the value if you don't need variations.

The result should be visible in material and render viewport shadings.
How to bake it
Baking Alpha should work as is, just like you did without even having to enable Film transparency:


Transmission
What is it
Transmission gives you a surface that both reflects light and transmits it into the interior of the object, like glass or liquids.
How to use it
The Principled BSDF controls the amount of transmission with its transmission weight property. Just as the Alpha (or any other socket), you can plug a texture to get variations, or manually write a value to get a constant result. Other properties like roughness and IOR will impact the reflections and refractions effects. But these are not what we bake in the transmission mask.
The result should be visible in material and render viewport shadings, but the material shading will show fake reflections by default for performance and quick previewing reasons, while the rendered shading will calculate real reflections from the surrounding scene.
How to bake it
Although there is no bake type for it, you can bake it indirectly by
plugging it into the material output node's surface socket and using the Emit bake type (if you use the Node Wrangler addon, you can simply ⎈ Ctrl⇧ Shift LMB the transmission mask).


After Baking
Regardless, the final result should be a BW image of your transmission or alpha mask, which you can save as a BW image (which then you can channelpack, to save memory (explanations)).


Ok adding checker texture did make glass transparent, but still the image is black
https://i.ibb.co/YW3CyGG/Transparent.png

So I understand you have one material assigned solely to your windows meshes. If you need the whole surface to have the same Alpha, you shouldn't plug a texture into the Alpha property, a straight value is enough. But regardless, if you did as I showed, it should bake correctly.

I noticed your image editor is set to show only color channels but not the alpha. You might have been successfully baking alpha correctly the whole time and just not have the viewer set to let you see it. See my edit.
